# splitting a sparse matrix into two

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Question: How can I split 1 sparse matrix into 2, based on the values in a list?

That is, I have a sparse matrix `X`:

```
>>print type(X)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

that I visualize in my head as a list of lists, to look like this:

```
>>print X.todense()
[[1,3,4]
 [3,2,2]
 [4,8,1]]
```

And I have a list `y` that looks like this:

```
y = [-1, 
      3, 
     -4]
```

How can I separate `X` into two sparse matrices, depending on whether the corresponding value in `y` is positive or negative? For example, how can I get:

```
>>print X_pos.todense()
 [[3,2,2]] 
>>print X_neg.todense()
 [[1,3,4]
  [4,8,1]]
```

The result (`X_pos` and `X_neg`) should also be sparse matrices obviously as it's just splitting a sparse matrix to begin with.

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: actually, this is pretty easy to achieve. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to generate two arrays of indices for the positive and negative `y` values, then use those to index into your sparse matrix.

```
>>> X = csr_matrix([[1,3,4], [3,2,2], [4,8,1]])
>>> y = np.array([-1, 3, -4])
>>> y_pos = np.where(y > 0)[0]
>>> y_neg = np.where(y < 0)[0]
>>> X_pos = X[y_pos]
>>> X_neg = X[y_neg]
```

You now have to CSR matrices containing the desired elements:

```
>>> X_pos
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> X_neg
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> X_pos.A
array([[3, 2, 2]])
>>> X_neg.A
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [4, 8, 1]])
```

Comment: You don't have two sparse matrices here. Indexing into a CSR matrix is not cheap. Usually one uses sparse matrices because one cares about performance. Of course it is trivial to solve if you don't care about performance. I expect that OP wants two CSR matrices efficiently produced from the CSR input. That's non-trivial.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I do have two sparse matrices here; the `.A` (abbreviation for `.toarray()`) converts them to dense arrays for viewing convenience. And "efficient row slicing" is one of the things that CSR matrices are actually designed for, according to [their docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

Comment: OK. The bit where you index into the original CSR matrix is surely expensive. Just imagine how you would implement it. Starting from a CSR matrix and creating a new one with all elements meeting a particular criteria removed isn't too hard. Just a single pass through the values array with col indices and row pointers suitably updated. But that's not what is happening here. I think.

Comment: That indexing, `X_pos = X[y_pos]` can be very efficient if the code can assume that `y_pos` is ordered. Otherwise it's going to be a bit more expensive but it can still be done efficiently. FWIW, I don't think this is row slicing, but that's moot. So, I retract my objections. Assuming numpy is well implemented, this should be very efficient. +1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you're right, this is not slicing, my mistake. However, I have used this before with moderately large datasets and it's usually fast enough, even though it can take quite some memory.